# fortranの長さ0の配列について

Tags: fortran

**状況**
fortranで書かれている物理関係のシミュレーションプログラムのデバッグを行っていますが、type定義の中に長さ0の配列が存在します。私が書いたコードでもなく、普段は別の言語を使っているので、その意味がわかりませんでした。

下記の例の`zero_body(1:0)`のようなものです。変数名な適当につけました。Fortran77時代のコードなので、拡張子も*.fですが、コンパイル時も特に引っかからなく、バグが起こる箇所でもなかったので、当時はこういう書き方があったかな？ぐらいでスルーしてましたが、やはり気になって経験者の方々にお聞きしたいです。

**コード例**

```
type (something)
    character*20 name
    integer*4 zero_body(1:0)
    integer*4 nonzero_body(0:255)
end type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fortran](/questions/tagged/fortran) f77 は学生時代にちょっとやっただけですが [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) でたとえるなら
`std::vector<int> v;`
は 0 要素の配列を作りますし、オイラはこのソースコード断片を一切疑問に思いません。「ああ、あとで `v.resize(n);` とかするんだろう＝動的に要素数を変更するんだろう」と勝手に予測します。提示の例も後から `reshape` するんだろうと思うだけです。ファイルを読んでみないと要素数が決定できないとか普通の話。

もちろんはずれかもしれませんが。

Comment: なるほで、後で使うかもしれないが、もし使わなくても無駄にメモリーは使いたくないので定義だけしておく意味ということですね。勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。